# Bulk delete with complex where condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with around 30k rows and i have a situation where i have to delete some of them form the table. Issue is when i have to delete around 1000 rows individual delete is taking a lot of time. To avoid this i have tried to implement bulk delete. For one postgresql function i have a where condition with multiple checks.
eg:

```
DELETE FROM tbName WHERE id = id AND name = inputName AND key = inputKey;
```

Right now i'm passing single id, inputName and inputKey to the funciton.
Is any way where i can batch this delete operation where i can pass a list of conditions and delete multiple rows in a single call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple combinations of the three values into the statement.

```
delete from the_table
where (id, name, "key") in ( (1,'name one','key one'), 
                             (2,'name two', 'key two'), 
                             (3,'name three', 'key three')
                           );
```

Comment: Just a doubt, is the same possible in sqlserver?

Comment: Although it's standard SQL, I don't think SQL Server supports it.

Comment: It worked thanks. Just to confirm, should i be worrying about the number of where conditions i'm passing?